# sending json data to separate class and display on tableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I currently am sending my json data to a `Dictionary` in the same `ViewController`. I would like to send it to a class named Users. The data is being displayed onto a `TableView`.

```
import UIKit

class Users: NSObject {

    var name: String? 
}



class FriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
     var userList = [Users]()

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


final let urlString = "https://api.lookfwd.io/v1/test/users"

 var namesArray = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return namesArray.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    myCell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
    return myCell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.downloadJsonWithTask()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func downloadJsonWithTask() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as URL?)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

    downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

        if let dataArray = (jsonData! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "users") as? NSArray {
            for data in dataArray{


      //          let user = Users()

       //         user.setValuesForKeys(data as! [String : Any])

        //        self.userList.append(user)


             if let dataDict = data as? NSDictionary {
                    if let title = dataDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                       self.namesArray.append(title as! String)
                    }
                }
            print(jsonData!)
            }
        }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        })

        print(jsonData!)

    }).resume()
}

}
```

Comment: Before append the user to userList, you need to convert your json as User model.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to perform an API call in one viewcontroller and wants to display the data in another controller?

Comment: No i want to send the data to my User Class and then display the names on my table view in the FriendsViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `downloadJsonWithTask` method

```
    func downloadJsonWithTask() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as URL?)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

    downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let response = data {
            if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                if let dataArray = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "users") as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for data in dataArray{
                        let newUser = Users(data: data)
                        self.userList.append(newUser)
                        print(jsonData!)
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    for use in self.userList {
                        print(use.name ?? "")
                    }

                    //reload your table here
                    // use name in cell for row at index as user.name
                })

                print(jsonData!)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

and your `User` model:

```
class Users: NSObject {
var name: String?

init(data:[String:Any]) {
    super.init()
    if let nameStr = data["name"] as? String {
        self.name = nameStr
    }
}
```

}

Try not to use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` as both are the older techniques, Go for the new one [], [:]

Answer (score 0):

In the Users class you need to pass the json data and assign the class variables with the corresponding data.

```
import UIKit
class Users: NSObject {

    var name: String? 
   required init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
    super.init()
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
}

}
```

You can modify the part in downloadJSONTask where you parse the dictionary as

```
if let dataDict = data as? NSDictionary {
                    let users = Users.init(dictionary: dataDict)
                    if let title = dataDict.value(forKey: "name") {

                       self.namesArray.append(title as! String)
                    }
}
```